# Zooming in at the center of InteractiveViewer using Matrix4 transformation

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having an InteractiveViewer widget that holds the image.

How can I scale the InteractiveViewer using TransformationController so that when user taps a button, the InteractiveViewer would zoom in for some arbitrary zoom level at the current center of the InteractiveViewer?

I have tried using

```
final currentScale = _transformationController.value.getMaxScaleOnAxis();
_transformationController.value = Matrix4.identity()..scale(currentScale * 1.1);
```

and while this zooms in as expected, it resets the current position to the top left corner of the InteractiveViewer, which is not what I want.

My intended behavior is that the view does not reset to the top left corner but instead zooms in at the center of currently visible viewport.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/pskink/aa0b0c80af9a986619845625c0e87a67#file-transform_entry-dart-L39

Comment: @pskink thank you for your reply. the only thing i cannot seem to understand now is how i would get the current center offset of the current visible interactive viewer viewport. do you have any tips to point me in the right direction?

Comment: you can wrap interactive viewer with `LayoutBuilder`

Comment: I did. Then calculated offset as following: Offset(constraints.maxWidth / 2, constraints.maxHeight / 2);

But this does not give me relative center that moves with InteractiveViewer. The value is always the same.

Comment: and the you have to pass that offset to `toScene` method

Comment: @pskink ok that is great, I can see it at the center of the screen at all times now. But when I call ..translate(x, y) on Matrix it is still jumping to some weird location. Would I need to convert these toScene values further?

Comment: why would you want to call `translate`?

Comment: @pskink  I need to call `translate` to get the matrix to the current center, right? Otherwise how would the matrix get scaled into the current center?

Comment: i gave you a link in my first comment, use `composeMatrixFromOffsets`, also you can check the first example from the same file, see how it is called here https://gist.github.com/pskink/aa0b0c80af9a986619845625c0e87a67#file-transform_entry-dart-L441

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve my issue. Big shoutout to @pskink and my co-worker. This implementation will zoom in depending on your current position.

```
final x = Offset(constraints.maxWidth / 2, constraints.maxHeight / 2);
final offset1 = _transformationController.toScene(x);
_transformationController.value.scale(1.1);
final offset2 = _transformationController.toScene(x);
final dx = offset1.dx - offset2.dx;
final dy = offset1.dy - offset2.dy;
_transformationController.value.translate(-dx, -dy);
```

`constraints.maxWidth` and `constraints.maxHeight` come from the `LayoutBuilder` wrapped around `InteractiveViewer` widget.

Here is implementation from @pskink that zooms in at the center:

```
class FooMatic extends StatefulWidget {
  const FooMatic({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FooMatic> createState() => _FooMaticState();
}

class _FooMaticState extends State<FooMatic> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TransformationController ctrl = TransformationController();
  late Size size;
  late AnimationController animationCtrl = AnimationController(
    vsync: this,
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    animationCtrl.addListener(_animationTick);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: animationCtrl.forward, child: const Text('zoom in')),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: animationCtrl.reverse, child: const Text('zoom out')),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              size = constraints.biggest;
              return Stack(
                children: [
                  InteractiveViewer(
                    transformationController: ctrl,
                    constrained: false,
                    child: const FlutterLogo(size: 1000),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 32,
                      height: 32,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 2),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            }
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _animationTick() {
    final center = size.center(Offset.zero);
    final anchor = ctrl.toScene(center);
    ctrl.value = composeMatrixFromOffsets(
      scale: ui.lerpDouble(1, 2, animationCtrl.value)!,
      anchor: anchor,
      translate: center,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think just using `alignment` properties, this is work on my code:

```dart
TransformationController transformationController = TransformationController();

InteractiveViewer(
   alignment: Alignment.center,
   maxScale: 5,
   minScale: 1,
   transformationController: transformationController,
   child: Image.network("https://picsum.photos/1000"),
)
```